# Image overflow hidden not behaving correctly

Tags: html, css

I'm stuck using a specific blog layout for a Wordpress theme. I have modified it but am having issues getting a 1920px by 550px image to center and hide the overflow. At the moment, the image is just becoming stretched.

Link to the blog in question: http://goo.gl/5Id68s

**Code:**

```css
.template-blog .big-preview {
  padding: 0 0 0px 0;
  width: 1920px;
}

.template-blog .big-preview img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 510px;
  background-position: center center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="big-preview single-big">

  <a href="sample.com" title="Sample Image" class="lightbox-added">

    <img width="1920" height="550" src="http://goo.gl/e9Xt8y" class="attachment-entry_without_sidebar wp-post-image">

  </a>
</div>
```

Appreciate the assistance!

Answer (score 2):

Apply the `overflow` and its value to `.big-preview` or whatever that contains the image instead. The Image can't overflow itself.

```css
.big-preview {
  overflow: hidden;
   width: 100%;
  height: 510px;
  }

.big-preview img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
 
}
```

```html
<div class="big-preview single-big">

  <a href="sample.com" title="Sample Image" class="lightbox-added">

    <img width="1920" height="550" src="http://goo.gl/e9Xt8y" class="attachment-entry_without_sidebar wp-post-image">

  </a>
</div>
```

**Note:** You can use negative values of margin property to get it to center. E.G `margin-left: -100px`.

Comment: I tried your solution, I believe it's what I originally had. It's still stretching the image. Here is a direct link to the blog, that might be more helpful for you: http://goo.gl/5Id68s  You'll see that the image is not stretching but also not centering. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry man, it's not working out for me. Can you provide a fiddle at all? If I make it a %, the image just stretches out of shape as the viewport changes. I'd like it to just center the image and keep the image at a static 1920x550 size. If this isn't possible, I might just have to use a few media sizes to determine the best negative margins (which I dislike doing). Thanks again!

Comment: As the window shrinks, the image height becomes 403px instead of 510px. On a 1920 x 1080 monitor, your code works perfectly well. But the picture keeps the same aspect ratio and shrinks when the viewport is reduced instead of staying centered and cropping.

Answer (score 0):

You can center your header by applying `margin: 0 auto;` to your style

```
#top .fullsize .template-blog .big-preview {
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    width: 1920px;
}
```

If you need to center the image, adding `text-align: center;` to its parent block element will center the image as images are inline elements

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This unfortunately did not work for me. Can you take a look at the blog post link I posted in my original post to see if you can get it to function properly?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, posting an image of your expected result would make it easier. Cropped and centered header from the code above looks like this http://i.imgur.com/MBehp68.jpg?1